# How to customize gSOAP XML-generation of fixed arrays?

Tags: c, xml, parsing, gsoap

Main outputs of this are .wsdl and .xsd:

```
$ soapcpp2 -c tmp.h
```

Relevant part of tmp.h is:

```
/* .. */
struct s_t
{
    long an_array[4] 1:1;
    long another[5] 0:1;
};
/* .. */
```

XML samples are also generated. Is there a way to have influence on XML-output as well?

1. `eventTS` tags have timestamp values so every generation differs (more difficult to compare)
2. There are unnecessary comments: `<!-- spam, spam and spam -->`
3. Arrays larger than 4 are listed as their size were 2:

   ```
   <another SOAP-ENC:arrayType="xsd:long[2]">

   <item>0</item>

   <item&>0</item>

   </another>;
   ```

Is there a way to turn off timestamps, comments in XML-generation and modify threshold to generate arrays of size - for example - 8 properly?

Comment: Please see the soapcpp2 options: `-u uncomment comments in WSDL/schema output by suppressing XML comments`. Sample messages are limited in size with a purpose, so arrays are shown only for a limited number of elements. What do you mean with "eventTS tags have timestamp values so every generation differs (more difficult to compare)"?

Comment: @Alex, thanks. In v2.7.1 there was not -u switch, but I have moved to v2.8.24r, so it is ok. As for timestamps, yes, it would be easier to compare results. And I thought that array limitation in XML samples have this purpose, but in gsoap/src/symbol2.c there are only branches `if( 2 < idx ) { idx = 4; }` or sg like that without a single comment line or confirmation in doc. In the end I customized that code due to set the limit to e. g. 30 but still in doubt about correct functionality.

Comment: When I tried this out I found that this issue was corrected in the latest gsoap 2.8.29 release.